# WOPI Service Unavailable

Tags: c#, .net-core, ms-wopi, office-online-server

I created WOPI host page .NET Core web app and WOPI handler .NET Core web api app. I tested everything with `.wopitest` file and it works fine.
But when I switched to work with `.docx`, `.xlsx` etc I see error `Service Unavailable We are currently experiencing technical difficulties. Please try again later.`

Discovery XML url: `https://ffc-onenote.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery`

and I tried `https://onenote.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery`

How can I resolve this? Maybe I can debug/log it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in my url:

`wopi/{param}/files/{id}` I thought it starts with "wopi" and in the end "/files/{id}"

but right url:

`wopi/{param}/wopi/files/{id}`

So as I understood required url: `.../wopi/files/{id}` or `.../wopi_{something}/files/{id}`

The documentation below seems a bit confusing.

[WOPI REST endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/endpoints#endpoint-urls)